# Angularjs Filter array using property inside other object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have the following Json File...

ill Show u only 1 object...
i have 154 with the same structure i want filter the name... when in **art_type.name** = '--Something...--'

```
{
"1": {
    "name": "Miami City Ballet",
    "created": "2011-04-24 00:39:28",
    "modified": "2015-09-02 09:30:49",
    "author": [],
    "slug": "miami-city-ballet",
    "address": "2200 Liberty Ave.",
    "city": "Miami Beach",
    "state": "Fl.",
    "zipcode": "33139",
    "phone_number": "Box Office: 305 929 7010",
    "email_address": "eparkinson@miamicityballet.org",
    "web_address": "http://www.miamicityballet.org",
    "twitter_address": "https://twitter.com/MiamiCityBallet",
    "facebook_address": "https://www.facebook.com/miamicityballetschool",
    "instagram_address": "",
    "gallery_hours": "<div><span style=\"line-height: 1.4em;\">order </span><span style=\"line-height: 1.4em;\">by phone 1 877 929 710</span></div>\n<div>or in person</div>\n<div><b>Box Office Hours:</b></div>\n<div>Mon - Fri: 10 - 5</div>\n<div><b>Tickets start at $25</b></div>\n<div>Grand Opening:</div>\n<div><b>Friday, October 23, 8 pm</b></div>\n<div><b>Arsht Center</b></div>",
    "gallery_id": "46",
    "additional_details": "October 23 - November 15\n<h3>Program One:</h3>\n<div>Swan Lake – Balanchine/Tchaikovsky</div>\n<div>Viscera – Scarlett/Liebermann</div>\n<div>Fancy Free – Robbins/Bernstein</div>",
    "gallery_additional_info": "Swan Lake is the most famous of all ballets, its name practically synonymous with the art form. Miami City Ballet is excited to be bringing back to our audiences the glorious version of Acts Two and Four – the “white acts” – that George Balanchine created in 1951 for Maria Tallchief and New York City Ballet. More than a tragic romance, it is a timeless meditation on the universal experience of love and loss, set to Tchaikovsky’s most evocative score.",
    "critics_choice": "0",
    "circuit": {
        "6": {
            "name": "Art Is Everywhere",
            "created": "2011-04-24 00:33:19",
            "modified": "2011-04-24 00:33:19",
            "author": false,
            "slug": "art-is-everywhere",
            "id": 6
        }
    },
    "art_type": {
        "1": {
            "name": "Performing Arts",
            "created": "2011-04-24 00:29:55",
            "modified": "2011-04-24 00:29:55",
            "author": false,
            "slug": "performing-arts",
            "id": 1
        }
    },
    "monthly_update": {
        "ID": "273",
        "post_author": "1",
        "post_date": "2011-04-14 16:45:58",
        "post_date_gmt": "2011-04-14 21:45:58",
        "post_content": "April 1 - 3\r\nKravis Center for the Performing Arts\r\n\r\nApril 29 - May 1\r\nBroward Center for the Performing Arts\r\n<strong> Program IV - Romeo and Juliet</strong>\r\nThe Company Premiere of John Crankoâ€™s version\r\n<em>The New York Times raves, â€œarguably the best dance treatment of Prokofievâ€™s celebrated score.â€</em>\r\n<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"2\" cellpadding=\"1\" width=\"350\" align=\"center\">\r\n<tbody>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\">\r\n<div><img src=\"http://www.artcircuits.com/newsletters/images/Jennifer-Kronenberg-and-Carlos-Guerra-11.jpg\" alt=\"image\" width=\"100\" height=\"74\" align=\"top\" /></div></td>\r\n<td height=\"100\" align=\"center\" valign=\"top\">\r\n<div><img src=\"http://www.artcircuits.com/newsletters/images/2Jennifer-Kronenberg-and-Carlos-Guerra-11.jpg\" alt=\"image\" width=\"98\" height=\"127\" align=\"top\" /></div></td>\r\n<td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\">\r\n<div><img src=\"http://www.artcircuits.com/newsletters/images/Carlos-11.jpg\" alt=\"image\" width=\"100\" height=\"99\" /></div></td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td width=\"100\" align=\"center\" valign=\"top\">\r\n<div>Jennifer Kronenberg and Carlos Guerra in Romeo and Juliet. Photo Â© 2009 Lois Greenfield.</div></td>\r\n<td width=\"100\" height=\"0\" align=\"center\" valign=\"top\">\r\n<div>Jennifer Kronenberg and Carlos Guerra in Romeo and Juliet. Photo Â© 2009 Lois Greenfield.</div></td>\r\n<td width=\"100\" height=\"0\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">\r\n<div>Carlos Guerra in Romeo and Juliet. Photo Â© 2009 Lois Greenfield.</div></td>\r\n</tr>\r\n</tbody>\r\n</table>\r\nMore<a href=\"http://www.miamicityballet.org/\"> www.miamicityballet.org</a>",
        "post_title": "Miami City Ballet - April 2011",
        "post_excerpt": "",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "comment_status": "open",
        "ping_status": "open",
        "post_password": "",
        "post_name": "miami-city-ballet-april-2011",
        "to_ping": "",
        "pinged": "",
        "post_modified": "2011-04-14 16:54:57",
        "post_modified_gmt": "2011-04-14 21:54:57",
        "post_content_filtered": "",
        "post_parent": "0",
        "guid": "http://artcircuits..com/?p=273",
        "menu_order": "505",
        "post_type": "post",
        "post_mime_type": "",
        "comment_count": "0",
        "pod_item_id": "273"
    },
    "thumbnail": false,
    "caption": "<!-- [if gte mso 9]><xml>\n<o:DocumentProperties>\n<o:Template>Normal.dotm</o:Template>\n<o:Revision>0</o:Revision>\n<o:TotalTime>0</o:TotalTime>\n<o:Pages>1</o:Pages>\n<o:Words>33</o:Words>\n<o:Characters>191</o:Characters>\n<o:Company>lpa2790</o:Company>\n<o:Lines>1</o:Lines>\n<o:Paragraphs>1</o:Paragraphs>\n<o:CharactersWithSpaces>234</o:CharactersWithSpaces>\n<o:Version>12.0</o:Version>\n</o:DocumentProperties>\n<o:OfficeDocumentSettings>\n<o:AllowPNG></o:AllowPNG>\n</o:OfficeDocumentSettings>\n</xml><![endif]--><!-- [if gte mso 9]><xml>\n<w:WordDocument>\n<w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom>\n<w:TrackMoves>false</w:TrackMoves>\n<w:TrackFormatting></w:TrackFormatting>\n<w:PunctuationKerning></w:PunctuationKerning>\n<w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>18 pt</w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>\n<w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>18 pt</w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>\n<w:DisplayHorizontalDrawingGridEvery>0</w:DisplayHorizontalDrawingGridEvery>\n<w:DisplayVerticalDrawingGridEvery>0</w:DisplayVerticalDrawingGridEvery>\n<w:ValidateAgainstSchemas></w:ValidateAgainstSchemas>\n<w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>\n<w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent>\n<w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>\n<w:Compatibility>\n<w:BreakWrappedTables></w:BreakWrappedTables>\n<w:DontGrowAutofit></w:DontGrowAutofit>\n<w:DontAutofitConstrainedTables></w:DontAutofitConstrainedTables>\n<w:DontVertAlignInTxbx></w:DontVertAlignInTxbx>\n</w:Compatibility>\n</w:WordDocument>\n</xml><![endif]--><!-- [if gte mso 9]><xml>\n<w:LatentStyles DefLockedState=\"false\" LatentStyleCount=\"276\">\n</w:LatentStyles>\n</xml><![endif]-->\n\n<!-- [if gte mso 10]>\n\n<style>\n /* Style Definitions */\ntable.MsoNormalTable\n{mso-style-name:\"Table Normal\";\nmso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;\nmso-tstyle-colband-size:0;\nmso-style-noshow:yes;\nmso-style-parent:\"\";\nmso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;\nmso-para-margin:0in;\nmso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;\nmso-pagination:widow-orphan;\nfont-size:12.0pt;\nfont-family:\"Times New Roman\";\nmso-ascii-font-family:Cambria;\nmso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;\nmso-fareast-font-family:\"Times New Roman\";\nmso-fareast-theme-font:minor-fareast;\nmso-hansi-font-family:Cambria;\nmso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;}\n</style><![endif]-->\n\n<!--StartFragment-->\n<h3></h3>\n<h3></h3>\n<!--EndFragment-->",
    "id": 1
},
```

this is my full json http://artcircuits.com/wp-json/pods/art_places.... use some json online viewer

```
<ion-view view-title="WYNWOOD ARTS DISTRICT">
<ion-content class="padding" style="background-color: #E5E5E4; color:#8B7447; top:54px">
         <ul class="list" ng-repeat="equis in arreglo">
                <a href="#" class="item " >{{equis.name}}</a>

        </ul>
```

well i have all my object.. in one $scope.variable...
i want to do the next...

FILTER by **art_type array** property **name or index**....

Please i need a simple solution... maybe do the filter in controller... or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is in two steps:

1. "flatten" the object into an array that's easier to filter. (in my example I'm using lodash to do this)
2. use the regular angular filter in the markup.

Here's the [example](http://jsbin.com/gamiyu/edit?html,js,output)

And here's inline code:
HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in arr | filter: {art_type:filterByArtType}">
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.filterByArtType = 1;
  $scope.obj = {
    "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Miami City Ballet",
    ...
    "art_type": {
        "1": {
          "name": "Performing Arts"
        }
      }
     ...
    },
     ...
  };

  $scope.arr = _.chain($scope.obj)
    .values()
    .map( function(n) {
      n.art_type = _.keys(n.art_type)[0];
      return n;
    }).value();
});
```

UPDATE: Now making the flattened array's "art_type" value be the "id" instead of the name.

Comment: ok this works, but i have little problem with the $scope.obj... 
Please help me with this...  $scope.obj=$rootScope.todo;
where $rootScope.todo is all the array ... When i put ur way to do the thing  works.. but with my full array dont... i dont know if im write something wrong. or the my format array is the problem...

Comment: oh, I think I see the problem ... "art_type" key is not always "1". I'll update the example soon.

Comment: Thanks u so much... works this method ill use in many parts of the projects. tell me how i can help u?... with reputation or something more...

Comment: Thanks @Raphael glad that helped

Comment: only for the record how i can doit with the regular angular filter in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the angular built-in `filter` filter. It can be used in an `ng-repeat` to restrict which elements of an array are used for generating elements in the DOM, without modifying the source array.

[Official angular documentation for filter filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Comment: yes i understand ur point... but i want know how to write the ng-repeat with  the filter directive correctly with my problem... Filte by art_type... if un know how doit please let me know

Comment: The first line in that documentation reads "Selects a subset of items from array and returns it as a new array." But OP does not have an array, it's an object of objects.